# What happens after "return Json(myObject);"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm observing a very strange behavior in my application.
pls look at this:
[image]
A given page reaches out to 5 API operations via ajax. The weird thing is that, when execute at once, in a concurrent manner, the sum of the response time is around 10-100 times slower than a sequential one.
I have, in my application 2 types of telemetry logs. One is the application insights provided by MS itself, and a rudimentary HttpModule that handles the `BeginRequest` and the `EndRequest` events logging the time it took.
The thing is that the information from both and fiddler are not consistent. The httpModule logs match the fiddler representation **always**, but the application insights **only** match when the requests are issued sequentially.
The data I get from application insights leads me to believe that the requests are always sequential.

Looking for possibilities and explanations, I've eliminated database transaction related issues (since those are read operations, deadlocks are not happening), code locking (no locks happen) and others because until the "return Json(something);" the behavior is 100% consistent. Now, I have only 1 place to look: the place between the `finally` block and the handling of the `EndRequest` event.

So, what happens there? What can be the cause of this "lag"?!?

Extra Info:
The Application Insights logging are like this:

```
public JsonResult DoSomething(int id)
    {
        #region Trace
        Stopwatch st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        RequestTelemetry reqTel = new RequestTelemetry();
        TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry();
        traceTelemetry.Message = "Doing Somthing";
        traceTelemetry.SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Verbose;
        _logger.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
        #endregion
        try
        {
            var something = Work();
            #region Trace
            traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry();
            traceTelemetry.Message = "Returning Work";
            traceTelemetry.SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Verbose;
            _logger.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
            #endregion
            return Json(something);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(0);
        }
        finally
        {
            #region Trace
            st.Stop();
            reqTel.Duration = st.Elapsed;
            reqTel.Name = "DoSomething";
            reqTel.Url = HttpContext.Request.Url;
            reqTel.Properties.Add("Message", "Finally Block for DoSomething");
            reqTel.Properties.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            _logger.TrackRequest(reqTel);
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct, the reason is that every request in an ASP.NET locks the Session Object for the request. In other words there is always only one request for specific session being processed and others are being queued.

There is a way around this - you must specify that specific request can be server without access to session (or with read-only access). In case of ASP.NET MVC you can do that by using `SessionStateAttribute` with value of `ReadOnly` or `Disable` over your controller

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    ...
}
```

If you require write access to session there is no way around this.

Comment: @Leonardo Exactly

Comment: i implemented the ReadOnly alternative and things are really sweet now! tks a lot!